# Programmatically draw a circle using lines

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry

How can i draw a circle using lines, by having a constant pixel difference between points?

I have been trying to edit this algorithm

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var step = 2 * Math.PI / 22; //(22 points)
var h = 250;
var k = 250;
var r = 105;

ctx.beginPath(); //tell canvas to start a set of lines

for (var theta = 0; theta < 2 * Math.PI; theta += step) {
  var x = h + r * Math.cos(theta);
  var y = k - r * Math.sin(theta);

  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.stroke();
}

ctx.closePath();
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  border: thin solid grey;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
```

This algorithm draws a circle which has 22 points. How can i change this algorithm so that a pixel difference between two points will always be a value, for example 50 pixels between each point?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc ?

Comment: "50 pixels between points" does not define a unique circle. Imagine both a square and a triangle with side-lengths of 50.

Comment: @Taplar i want to draw it using lines

Comment: So change the step value....

Comment: Do you mean 50 pixels from the center (radius)? If you mean between each point, that would be a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl i mean 50 between each point

Comment: OK, I updated my response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the distance between the points to be consistent, you can calculate the radius given the number of points (aka sides) and the distance you want the points to be apart from one another.

```
x = (distance / 2) / sine(step / 2)
```

[image: sample image]

```js
const sides = 3;
const distance = 100;
const step = Math.PI * 2 / sides;
const radius = (distance / 2) / Math.sin(step / 2); // 57.735
```

---

## Demo

In the example below, eight (odd-sided) polygons are drawn with each adjacent point 50 pixels from one another.

```js
const DEBUG = true;

const main = () => {
  const
    ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d'),
    origin = { x: ctx.canvas.width / 2, y: ctx.canvas.height / 2 },
    distance = 50, maxPoints = 18, start = 3, step = 2;

  for (let points = start; points < maxPoints; points += step) {
    drawCircle(ctx, origin.x, origin.y, distance, points);
  }
};

const drawCircle = (ctx, x, y, distance, sides) => {
  if (sides < 2) throw new Error('Circle must have 3 or more sides');
  const
    vector = (x, y, radius, theta) => ({
      x: x + radius * Math.cos(theta),
      y: y + radius * Math.sin(theta)
    }),
    d = 2 * Math.PI,
    step = d / sides,
    radius = (distance / 2) / Math.sin(step / 2),
    limit = d + step;

  // Display 
  if (DEBUG) {
    const
      d2 = distance / 2, h = ctx.canvas.height / 2,
      y1 = h - d2, y2 = h + d2, x1 = 0, x2 = ctx.canvas.width;
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.setLineDash([2, 5]);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y1);
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y2);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.setLineDash([]);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  for (let theta = 0; theta < limit; theta += step) {
    const { x: xOffset, y: yOffset } = vector(x, y, radius, theta);
    ctx.lineTo(xOffset, yOffset);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
};

main();
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  border: thin solid grey;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
```